# Problem adding WFS Layer to QGIS project

Tags: qgis, wfs

I want to load data using an WFS into QGIS 1.7.4.
After connection to the server is established, data seems to be downloaded, but no data is displayed in QGIS, neither geometry nor attributes.

The data is in EPSG:31467. I have changed the coordinate system in the QGIS WFS settings to EPSG:31467. It is then displayed as being set to 'urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG31467'.

On another machine, there is no problem adding the data.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If it's WFS 1.1, then this is a known issue: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4124

Comment: WFS 1.1 seems to be resolved in QGIS 3.16 per https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html#wfs-and-wfs-t-client  and testing with https://demo.gatewaygeomatics.com/cgi-bin/wfs_gateway?VERSION=1.1.0